# How to get the contents created by a User?

Tags: users

How to get all contents from which the current user is author?

```
 $currentUser = \Drupal::currentUser();
 $user = User::load($currentUser->id());
//get the contents from which $user is author?
```

Comment: "Content" could mean a lot of things-- nodes? entities? comments? etc.

Comment: i am interested particularely by nodes and medias , but all entities would do

Comment: There isn't an API for querying across multiple entity types - you need to use an `entityQuery` (or `loadByProperties`) for each type you're interested in, with a condition for the author field based on the user id. If you want to write something generic, you can inspect the entity keys to see what field the entity type uses as its `owner`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$currentUser = \Drupal::currentUser();
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
$query->condition('uid', $currentUser->id());
$author_nids=$query->execute();
```